# My JavaScript won't load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been struggling trying to figure it out why my JavaScript code won't run.

**Can anybody tell me what I missed ?** :(

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kpwk273p/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="po-markup">
    <br>
    <a href="#" class="po-link">Hover me </a>
    <div class="po-content hidden">
        <div class="po-title">
            <img src="http://g.etfv.co/http://www.cnn.com" alt="Google" width="16" height="16" />
            Title
        </div> 
        <div class="po-body">
            <p>
                Any Description .... 
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

**JS**
[image: JS]

Comment: Can you paste your code as *text* and not just a screenshot of it?

Comment: If you align your brackets/parentheses, you'll see the problem

Comment: Thank you for all of your comments. Someone had already point out what did I do wrong. Thank you all for trying to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should close `});`

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.po-markup > .po-link').popover({
        trigger: 'hover',
        html: true,  // must have if HTML is contained in popover

        // get the title and conent
        title: function() {
            return $(this).parent().find('.po-title').html();
        },
        content: function() {
            return $(this).parent().find('.po-body').html();
        },

        container: 'body',
        placement: 'right'

    });    //add it
});
```

also you should add bootstrap e.g 3.2.0 version

and you should add jquery library in your code e.g. on `onLoad` page

this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kpwk273p/6/)

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of issues with your jsfiddle

- You aren't referencing jQuery
- You aren't referencing a library that
  defines popover()
- Your Javascript isn't correctly formed; you need to close the function and call with `});`

Answer (score 1):

I forked your fiddle and got it to work:
http://jsfiddle.net/d2j79z8m/

You had a missing `});`